# Get key value of a key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I don't find how to get the value of a key pressed.
I currently have

```
$('#info_price').bind('keydown',function(evt){
    alert(evt.keyCode);
```

but it return '49' when I press on 1 instead of returning '1'.

Edit: I'm aware that Ascii code of key '1'.

The final goal is to allow people to only write digit into the input. So i want to detect the non digit and not display them.

Comment: 49 is the [Ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of key '1'

Comment: @Andreas That's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As it's told in comment it's `ASCII` code. To get it as character you can do:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode));
```

Comment: Note that key codes are not the same thing as character codes. For simple keys their codes correspond to their character counterparts, but for e.g. letter keys it results in uppercase letters. You'd need [the `keypress` event](http://jsfiddle.net/3wThj/) to get the character codes.

Comment: So for an azerty keyboard I need to press shift+1 to display one. As i'm pressing shift first, this solution is not working as well.

Comment: @bl0b: `keypress` may work, see the link in my comment above.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will give you incorrect values if you use the right side of your keyboard ( numbers ) .

Comment: This always gives capital letters, even when you're not pressing shift

Comment: () shift (Þ) '   its return a weird symbol for non alphabeth keys.

Comment: *Note*: `keyCode` has been deprecated, use `code` instead. [See MDN](https://devdocs.io/dom/keyboardevent/code)

Comment: @hitautodestruct This answer is 10 years old. lol. Feel free to suggest an edit of the answer, I will review and approve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

For those who google it now, like I am

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
});​
```

Comment: So simple - best one yet.

Comment: e.key always gives "Unidentified" on my android tablet.

Comment: By pressing the SHIFT key, it's also getting it as value.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fully done code for you to work with (not mine, but I used it):

> http://www.selfcontained.us/2009/09/16/getting-keycode-values-in-javascript/

```
keycode = {

    getKeyCode : function(e) {
        var keycode = null;
        if(window.event) {
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        }else if(e) {
            keycode = e.which;
        }
        return keycode;
    },

    getKeyCodeValue : function(keyCode, shiftKey) {
        shiftKey = shiftKey || false;
        var value = null;
        if(shiftKey === true) {
            value = this.modifiedByShift[keyCode];
        }else {
            value = this.keyCodeMap[keyCode];
        }
        return value;
    },

    getValueByEvent : function(e) {
        return this.getKeyCodeValue(this.getKeyCode(e), e.shiftKey);
    },

    keyCodeMap : {
        8:"backspace", 9:"tab", 13:"return", 16:"shift", 17:"ctrl", 18:"alt", 19:"pausebreak", 20:"capslock", 27:"escape", 32:" ", 33:"pageup",
        34:"pagedown", 35:"end", 36:"home", 37:"left", 38:"up", 39:"right", 40:"down", 43:"+", 44:"printscreen", 45:"insert", 46:"delete",
        48:"0", 49:"1", 50:"2", 51:"3", 52:"4", 53:"5", 54:"6", 55:"7", 56:"8", 57:"9", 59:";",
        61:"=", 65:"a", 66:"b", 67:"c", 68:"d", 69:"e", 70:"f", 71:"g", 72:"h", 73:"i", 74:"j", 75:"k", 76:"l",
        77:"m", 78:"n", 79:"o", 80:"p", 81:"q", 82:"r", 83:"s", 84:"t", 85:"u", 86:"v", 87:"w", 88:"x", 89:"y", 90:"z",
        96:"0", 97:"1", 98:"2", 99:"3", 100:"4", 101:"5", 102:"6", 103:"7", 104:"8", 105:"9",
        106: "*", 107:"+", 109:"-", 110:".", 111: "/",
        112:"f1", 113:"f2", 114:"f3", 115:"f4", 116:"f5", 117:"f6", 118:"f7", 119:"f8", 120:"f9", 121:"f10", 122:"f11", 123:"f12",
        144:"numlock", 145:"scrolllock", 186:";", 187:"=", 188:",", 189:"-", 190:".", 191:"/", 192:"`", 219:"[", 220:"\\", 221:"]", 222:"'"
    },

    modifiedByShift : {
        192:"~", 48:")", 49:"!", 50:"@", 51:"#", 52:"$", 53:"%", 54:"^", 55:"&", 56:"*", 57:"(", 109:"_", 61:"+",
        219:"{", 221:"}", 220:"|", 59:":", 222:"\"", 188:"<", 189:">", 191:"?",
        96:"insert", 97:"end", 98:"down", 99:"pagedown", 100:"left", 102:"right", 103:"home", 104:"up", 105:"pageup"
    }

};
```

Comment: Not working for me. It fails to give 'A', when I press 'a' and the capslock in on.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript each key has associated with a  ASCII code
 as follows

```
                          1-49
                          2-50
```

like this
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

So you need to map this values according to the keypress event.

Comment: But each keyboard has a different map.

Answer (score 1):

The key code does not directly map to the character value. Instead, you need to look at the `keypress` event, which provides you with a `charCode` property. You can then use `String.fromCharCode` to turn that into a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect all key values like this:

[Here is working jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xVCFQ/4/)

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    var order = e.which;
    console.log(order);
});​
```

[Source.](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To get the character of the `ASCII`:

```
String.fromCharCode();
```

to turn `ASCII` into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Opera today have Read only property `data` in event object.

It is written on MDN that currently this feature is "Working Draft".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data