# Print the name of a Key when it is Pressed?

Tags: javascript, keypress, dom-events

Is it possible to get the name of a key when it is pressed:

```
field.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
function keyDown(event) {
    ...
}
```

For example when pressing the space key, I would like to get the string value: "space", or something along those lines. Is there an easy way to do this or do I require a library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key value of a key pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689995/get-key-value-of-a-key-pressed)

Comment: What is the `field`? Can you show your HTML and enough of your JavaScript so we can see what you're doing, and working with? Where did you want the key-name to show up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Character value from KeyCode in JavaScript... then trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772179/get-character-value-from-keycode-in-javascript-then-trim)

Comment: Im not looking for the keycode. I wouldnt say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the *keycode*, but not the name, because names vary across cultures, languages, etc., and JavaScript doesn't provide any means of getting the culture- and language-specific name appropriate to the current culture and language.

So the answer to "Is it possible to get the name of a key when it is pressed?" is: Not from anything built into JavaScript or the browser. You'll need lookup tables and/or a library. Beware that different keyboard layouts may give different mappings.

The **`keypress`** event gives you a character code for the matching character if there is one (on `event.charCode`, which you can use like `String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)`), but not `keydown` since not all `keydown`s generate characters (as distinct from other keypresses), and in fact sometimes it takes more than one `keydown` to create a character.

---

To get the keycode, just use:

```
var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
```

That will use `event.which` if it's present and truthy, or `event.keyCode` if it's present and truthy, or `0` if neither is present and truthy. Most browsers use `which`; many versions of IE use `keyCode`.

Since a key "name" would probably include modifiers, I'll mention that there are modifier flags available on the event as well: `event.shiftKey`, `event.ctrlKey`, `event.altKey`, and `event.metaKey`.

You'll see people telling you can use `String.fromCharCode(keyCode)` after doing the above to get a character for the key code. That's only true for a very small set of key codes, because **key codes are not character codes**. There is a small amount of overlap between the two, which is why people think you can do that. For instance, if you press <kbd>a</kbd> on your keyboard, on any keyboard I've ever heard of `String.fromCharCode(keyCode)` will give you `"A"` (and then you can use `event.shiftKey` to decide whether to make it lower case). But it falls down *quickly* when you get into anything beyond the 26 letters of the English alphabet (and probably the standard ten digits).

Comment: I guess we can get keyboard values from `String.fromCharCode()`. Issue is it will return same value for `a` and `A`

Comment: @Rajesh: Key codes aren't character codes. So that'll work for some, but not for all.

Comment: I am not looking for a keycode. So Im guessing I will have to use a library for this

Comment: @user3024235: Sadly, as far as I'm aware, yes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `event.key` or `event.code`, e.g:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  console.log(event.code);
});
```

So if we assume the user presses the key "k", the expected output would be: `k` and `KeyK`. Pressing "Alt", the expected output would be: `Alt` and `AltLeft`.

However, the case would be different with `keypress` as it doesn't detect any special keys as ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, META, etc... But it would still detect English alphabet and numerics.

---

**Sources:**

event.key - [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_key.asp)
event.code - [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_code.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this file](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Index.txt) and lookup the name of the character. Is this what you want?