# reveal.js keyboard mapping / java script key event codes ; don't add up

Tags: javascript, keyevent, reveal.js

I don't understand how I get the "correct" key codes for configuring the `keyboard` map of reveal.js. Some integers work, like 27 for `escape`, others don't like I need `Period` (`.`) and `F5` for a logitech presenter (and I don't want to mess with Xorg key mapping). This has no effect:

```
        Reveal.configure({
            keyboard: {
                46: () => { alert("period") },  // no effect
                'Period': () => { alert("period") }, // no effect
                27: () => { console.log('esc') },  // works
            }
        });
```

How would I find the correct numbers (?) to remap period and F5?

Comment: https://keycode.info/ gives good information on what keys provide what number. The `.` key (period) is `190`. If you don't want a key to do something, why not try passing `null`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you can you post that as answer

Comment: I'm not sure it's a helpful answer. "Here's a link to a site which might disappear. Also use `null` like their docs say"

Answer (score 0):

[This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725403/print-the-name-of-a-key-when-it-is-pressed) of getting key codes is *not correct*. This page works correctly: http://javascriptkeycode.com/

Here period is given as `190`, and F5 is given as `116`.