# How can I determine what a value would be after a keypress event BEFORE it is applied to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I have a textbox which a user will be typing a number into. I want to limit that number to a max of 5 million (5000000). I want to prohibit any keypresses which would cause that number to go above 5 million. I know I could wait for keyup and use the value then, but I want to prevent the keypress entirely.

How can I determine what the value of the textbox would be after a given keydown/keypress event is applied BEFORE it actually happens?

Edit: To make it clear, consider this scenario:

The box currently contains the number "4000000".

The user highlights the last number and changes it to a 1, so that it becomes "4000001"

But the user COULD have simply added a 1 to the end. The keydown event would look exactly the same, but the result would be outside the range of values I want to allow.

I need to know what the value of the box would be if the keydown event were applied normally, but I need to know before it happens.

To be clear, this post is NOT about limiting a text field to numbers-only. I'm capable of doing that.

Comment: Where is the code you have so far?

Comment: you can cancel events and this is not hard to do the basic research on

Comment: Solution with js event https://jsfiddle.net/pw9Lgzgk/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689995/get-key-value-of-a-key-pressed

Comment: You guys are missing the crux of the issue, so I've updated the question.

I can get the value of the keycode, but that does not tell me what the final value would be. What if he typed a character in the middle of the value instead of at the end? I have no way of knowing where it is being added, so I can't predict the value.

Comment: `$("textarea").on("keydown", function (e) {  e.preventDefault(); alert(e.keyCode);});`

Comment: Thank you, but I am capable of reading the keycode from an event.

This is not sufficient for my purposes, because it does not tell me what will actually happen when that event gets processed, for example if the user has a few characters selected when they type it, those letters will be replaced.

Comment: GOOD LUCK THEN!

Comment: I think you might have an XY problem here. If you want to cap the number at a certain ceiling, it is way easier to simply coerce the number regardless of user input or key events. Your approach is basically **trying to pre-empt ANY kind of user triggered events that can cause the value to overflow, yet key presses are just *one* of the many ways users can augment the numerical value**. Using the max attribute on input type number can also help to achieve the goal, otherwise you can use a simple JS based approach that coerced the value to a set ceiling on input, change, or blur events.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you looking for?

```js
var max = 4000000;
var last_value;

$('#someinput').on('input', function(e){
  var value = $(this).val();

  if(value<=max)
    last_value = value;
  else
    $(this).val(last_value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="someinput" type="number"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm looking for. This is the only way I can currently think to accomplish it, but this doesn't solve my problem because it allows the text to be added in the first place.

The reason I don't want to simply overwrite the text afterward is because I don't want the user to lose their cursor position because I'm doing it in a contenteditable div.